# argument parsing in python2.7

Tags: python

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('-r', action='store',dest='box',type=int,help='store')
print parser.parse_args()
```

when i try to run the above code o/p is

> >
>   Namespace(box=None)

when i give the "-r" the error rises.

> > -r
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "", line 1, in 
> >         -r
> >     NameError: name 'r' is not defined

how to fix this error!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You should go read up on what a command line argument *is*. You're typing `-r` into the Python interactive prompt, not providing it as a command-line argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just run it by
Python filename -r some integer value 
You would get your expected result

If u want the parameter to be optional use --r in .add_argument()

Answer (score -1):

it expects int value so first try putting -r in quotes and then after a space pass an integer value it will work. say for instance,the code is stored in a file named q1.py you can run it as:

python q1.py '-r' 5

on running this it is expected to give

Namespace(box=5)

Comment: The quotes are unnecessary.